# Alert message on paging in gridview

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I want to show an alert when user tries to do paging in gridview. I am using this script, but the alert pops up even if any of those buttons in the page is clicked in the page. I need to alert only when paging is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeEditorWarning() {
        return 'It looks like you have been editing something -- if you leave before submitting your changes will be lost.'
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = closeEditorWarning
</script>
```

Really appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What is "of those buttons is clicked"

Comment: Means I have button in the page.

Comment: Any postback is going to fire the unload event since the page needs to reload. Could you tie that script to the pager clicks in codebehind or markup?

Comment: Yeah I tied this script to pageindexing event, but no alert pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Write an java script alert inside `gridview_pageindexchanging()` event to do this:

**You can do this  by using Script Manager as follows:**

```
You have double script tags. Add the script tags yourself:

protected void grid_pageindexchanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
   string script = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('abc');</script>";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script);
}
```

Or **let the method add it:**

```
protected void grid_pageindexchanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
   string script = "alert('abc');";
   ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Alert", script, true);
}
```

**Hope this helps..**

**Updated:**

**try including the following:**

```
using  System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

***Updated 2:***

Can you try this now:

```
string script = "alert('its working now!')";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "its working",script,true);
```

Comment: I tried this and I don't see any alerts when paging is clicked.

Comment: Yes I'm using that, but no luck.

Comment: IN which event , you are calling javascript ?

Comment: Yeah the debug points hits the script, but the alert doesn't show up.

Comment: Yeah the alert comes. But I need to show like OK & CANCEL. If they click on OK then it will goto next page. If they click cancel then it has to stay on the same page.

Comment: @user3215411//then try using Confirm() instead of using Alert()

Comment: I tried it and now even the alert has stopped showing up. So just looking if I can tie a onclientclick to paging.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option, set a CSS class on the pager and associate your script with the click event for that class.

Untested but probably in the right direction:

```
$('.myClass').click(function () { closeEditorWarning; });
```